# Delphi using TFileStream for custom file extension

Tags: delphi

I have read about streams in the documentation and I have understood how they work, but I haven't understood when I should use them.

For example let's think that I have a program AAA.exe and it has to save some configurations; in this case I'll use a `ini` file. But I can also use a `TFileStream` with `TBinaryWriter` / `TBinaryReader` to create a file called (for example) `config.aaa`.

As you can see in the second example the `config.aaa` has a custom extension that I have invented and **only** I know how to read it (becasue the writing order and the reading order must be the same).

What is the difference in creating `config.ini` and `config.aaa`? Is the second option better or not? I know that it depends from the cases, but I'd like to know if it's a good option or not.

I guess that I could create a custom file with a custom extension to store particular data that ONLY my program can access.

Comment: An INI file is typically plain text, and will be text if you use TIniFile. TFileStream will allow you to write whatever you need to write in whatever format you need to write, including any text, binary or non-text data. What's difficult to understand? Whether the second option is better or not depends on what you need to do - which suits your needs better, plain text or some other format?

Comment: `TFileStream` is simply a stream wrapper for the `FileCreate()/FileOpen()`, `FileRead()`, `FileWrite()`, and `FileSeek()` functions.  So really, you should be asking yourself which is better in your situation - writing a textual INI file with `TIniFile`, or writing a custom binary file with manual file I/O.  It really depends on your situation, the type of data you are writing, and whether you want users to be able to view/edit the file content directly.

Comment: Streams and extensions are irrelevant. What really matters are the contents. What format do **you** want to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's two different questions at once.

When should you use a stream?

Streams are an abstraction for accessing data in a consistent way regardless of the specifics of the actual storage. For example, consider `TMemoryStream`, `TFileStream` and `TResourceStream`. All of these give you the same interface for reading and writing data, but the data is ultimately stored in very different places - memory, filesystem, PE files' resources. The important part here is that despite a significant difference of the underlying storage, the way of accessing the data through the stream is always the same. In fact, you could simply replace one stream with another (say, a stream for reading data over network), and your application would still work without any further changes.

So to answer your question, you should use streams every time it can possibly happen that you may want to change the storage device or modify its characteristics (e.g. add compression).

But this is completely independent of the actual data you store in the streams. It's up to you to interpret the data, a stream just gives you an unified way of accessing it, hiding device specifics from you. The **meaning** of the data is something completely different.

As for your files, there is no real difference between `config.ini` and `config.aaa` (or, indeed, `pink unicorn.mp3`). The filename and the extenion is just a label you give that file to make it easy to understand the contents, but the actual interpretation is independent of the name. This may seem strange to someone used to Windows, because on Windows we often use extensions as something which determines the contents of a file (unlike in the Unix world, where extensions have no meaning whatsoever); but even on Windows, you can notice that extensions don't really mean much - rename your photos from `something.jpg` to `somethingelse.png` or your videos from `movie1.avi` to `movie1.mp4` and you will likely notice that your viewer/player can show/play these just as well - simply because it doesn't care about the extension but scans the contents and decides how to show/play the file based on that content.

If you are under Windows, it makes sense to use the common extensions, because it will make it easy for others (or your future self) to guess at the contents of a file, but it is not mandatory.